# I am trying to bring data from MongoDB on clicking link but i am not able to get it as there is no error showing in console

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

**Unable to Fetch Data from Database Using MongoDB in Node.js**

I am building a web page using Node.js that includes a menu with options for `Home`, `Categories`, and `Products`. I have entered category-related records into MongoDB. However, when I click on the `"Categories"` menu option, the data is not being fetched from the database. Despite thorough debugging, I am unable to identify any errors in my code. I wrote `console.log()` under `mongodb.connect` but its not printing any thing in console. I guess `mongodb.connect` line is not working properly

Category.js file:

```js
let express = require("express");
let categoryRouter = express.Router();
let mongodb = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
let url = process.env.MongoUrl;

function router(menu) {
    categoryRouter.route("/").get(function (req, res) {
        mongodb.connect(url, function (err, dc) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send("Error While Connecting");
            } else {
                let dbObj = dc.db("may8");
                dbObj
                    .collection("category")
                    .find()
                    .toArray(function (err, response) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.status(500).send("Error While Fetching");
                        } else {
                            res.render("category", {
                                title: "Category",
                                data: response,
                                menu,
                            });
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
        //res.send(category)
    });

    categoryRouter.route("/details").get(function (req, res) {
        res.send("Category Details");
    });

    return categoryRouter;
}

module.exports = router;
```

app.js file:

```js
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
let port = process.env.PORT || 7600;
let fs = require("fs");
let morgan = require("morgan");
let helmet = require("helmet");

let menu = [
    { link: "/", name: "Home" },
    { link: "/category", name: "Category" },
    { link: "/products", name: "Products" },
           ];

let categoryRouter = require("./src/controller/categoryRouter")(menu);
let productRouter = require("./src/controller/productRouter")(menu);

app.use(morgan("short", { stream: fs.createWriteStream("./app.logs") }));
// app.use(helmet());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set("views", "./src/views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
          res.render("index", { title: "Home Page", menu: menu });
       });

app.use("/category", categoryRouter);
app.use("/products", productRouter);

app.listen(port, function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          else {
             console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
               }
         });
```

Comment: Is `console.log(url)` what you expect?

Comment: this is the value of MongoUrl="mongodb://localhost:27017" which is located in .env file i am expecting it should return this url only but the problem is the code is not executing from mongodb.connect line i checked it by debugging the code

Comment: Debugger skips the entire code from mongodb.connect line

Comment: What is `console.log(url)` immediately after `let url = process.env.MongoUrl;`?

Comment: url="mongodb://localhost:27017"

Comment: If you try `MongoUrl="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"`, does that work?  If not, you may want to look at `mongod.log` to see if there are any relevant messages from the MongoDB server.

Comment: MongoUrl="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017" its working but the code inside the function from this line mongodb.connect(url, function (err, dc) is not working i debugged the entire code inside the function and i found that debugger is skipping the code from this line  mongodb.connect(url, function (err, dc)

Comment: Is the local MongoDB server (`mongod`) running?

Comment: Yes its running